# Auto Refresh a DIv in a JSP which includes the output of a Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets, refresh

I have a servlet "Servlet1" which sends a table data including the  and other tags in a format to show in HTML

and I have included the servlet output into a jsp page as follows:

```
<div id="loadTable">
<jsp:include page="/Servlet1" />
</div>
```

No I want this div to auto refresh every 5 sec. Can anyone help me with that?

I tried the following but it didn't refresh at all (though I am getting initial output of the servlet into my jsp page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(
function ()
{
$.get('/Servlet1', function(data) {
      $('#loadTable').html(data);
    });
}, 5000); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `jsp`:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var interval = 5000;   //ms
    var refresh = function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Servlet1",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $('#loadTable').html(html);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    refresh();
                }, interval);
            }
        });
    };
    refresh();
});

<div id="loadTable"></div>
```

Comment: This is not working. If I put an alert just before $('#loadTable').html(html); then that alert is showing but the div isn't getting updated. 

please note the servlet is returning a html formatted data

Comment: @SarbarthaSengupta can you `alert` the value of `html` variable. e.g. what is exactly returned from servlet ?

Comment: alert was working but servlet content wasn't coming.
I shifter it to another jsp and put a page refresh in that jsp and included into this page instead of the servlet and that did work.

Comment: @SarbarthaSengupta So bottom line  - the main problem was the `servlet`? If the above answer was helpful - don't forget to upvote - if it solved your problem - don't forget to accept... Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

just try by using setInterval()
`setInterval(function(){  $('#loadTable').load('/Servlet')}, 3000);`